# Jumping when hover

Tags: css, animation, hover, elementor

I want to achieve a simple animation on hover in CSS, but while hovering off, the animation jumps/flicking and makes it look silly. Is there a way to avoid that? I want the dropdown image to disappear and the tag to slide back to its original place.

```
.elementor-widget-wp-widget-woocommerce_product_categories .product-categories li > a:before {
 background: url("/dropdown.svg") no-repeat center/contain;
 content: "";
 border: none;
 display: inline-block;
 height: 1em;
 opacity: 0;
 transform: rotate(-90deg);
 transition-property: margin,opacity;
 width: 1em;
}

.elementor-widget-wp-widget-woocommerce_product_categories .product-categories li > a:hover::before {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: .3s ease all;
}

.product-categories li > a:hover{
  margin-left: 30px; 
}

.elementor-widget-wp-widget-woocommerce_product_categories .product-categories li a:after {
   content: none;
}
```

Comment: margin occupies the actual space, you can use translate to move without jumps

Answer (score 0):

Always use `transform:` instead of margin for css animations, they don't change the occupied space.

For example your code here should be:

```
.elementor-widget-wp-widget-woocommerce_product_categories .product-categories li > a:before {
 transform: translateX(0px) rotate(-90deg);
 transition-property: transform,opacity;
}


.product-categories li > a:hover{
  transform: translateX(-30px) rotate(-90deg); 
}
```

We keep the `rotate` property the same in both as I assume you don't want that to change in this instance.